# How to fetch Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership name in proper format?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012

My PowerShell script goes like this:

```bsh
Get-ADUser -Property * -filter * | Select-Object @{Label="Member Of";Expression={
  %{Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName | Select-Object name}
}}
```

Output:

```
Member Of
---------
{@{name=XYZUsers}, @{name=GLOBAL_XYZ}, @{name=LOCAL_XYZ}, @{name=ABC_APPROVER}
{@{name=XYZUsers}, @{name=GLOBAL_XYZ}, @{name=LOCAL_XYZ}, @{name=ABC_APPROVER}
```

Where as I want output to be like this:

```
Member Of
---------
XYZUsers, GLOBAL_XYZ, LOCAL_XYZ
XYZUsers, GLOBAL_XYZ, LOCAL_XYZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object` may be what you need.

Try this:

```
Get-ADUser -property * -filter * | select-object @{Label = "Member Of";Expression = {%{Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name}}}
```

Alternatively I think you could also potentially simplify your code to this, but I don't have anywhere to test it right now:

```
Get-ADUser -property * -filter * | % {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName | Select-Object name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Select-Object` statements gives you custom objects with a property `name` (`@{name=...}`). You need to extract the value of this property (e.g. via the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object`) and then join the extracted group names to a string:

```
Get-ADUser -Property * -Filter * | Select-Object @{n='Member Of';e={
  (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName |
    Select-Object -Expand Name) -join ', '
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

get-aduser -property * -filter * | select-object @{Label = "Member Of";Expression = {%{Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $*.SamAccountName |foreach-Object {$*.name}}}}